# Android DownloadManager - Download apk and install it

Tags: java, android, android-intent, download, android-download-manager

I have looked everywhere to find out how to download a APK that is not from the market place. The APK is stored in my server. 
All the sample did not work.

I want my App to download an APK for my server and promt the user to install it.

So far I managed to download the apk onto the user sd. but I can't get he path where is it saved and get to install it.

```
private void downloadAPK() {
    String url="https://www.example.com/app.apk”;
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setTitle(“My App“);
    enqueue = downloadManager.enqueue(request);


      new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean downloading = true;

            while (downloading) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                     DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                        q.setFilterById(enqueue);

                        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(q);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                        int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                        if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                            downloading = false;
                        }

                        final int dl_progress = (int) ((double)bytes_downloaded / (double)bytes_total * 100f);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                Log.d("Prog", Integer.toString(dl_progress));
                            }
                        });


                        cursor.close();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }

            }

        }
    }).start();
}}


BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();


        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
             Log.w(“”, “Downloaded”)

        }
        else {
            //do something here
       }

    }
};


onCreate ...
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you can specify the location where you want the file to be saved. All you have to do is adding this line before setting the request to de DownloadManager :

```
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir (context, dirType, subPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Query about your download local file using the code below :

Note that :
will return null if the download failed.

```
String path = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))).getPath()
```